# Como contar o número de bits de um texto usando java

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um determinado aplicativo, vasculhei literalmente a internet e não achei como posso contar o numero de bits de uma determinada frase, alguém pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só precisa saber o número de bytes e multiplicar por 8.
Por exemplo:

```
System.out.println("teste".getBytes().length * 8); //40
```

Comment: E se o texto estiver codificado em utf-8? Pode existir caracteres que ocupam mais de 8 bits.

Comment: Anderson, por isso o "getBytes()" e não o tamanho da String diretamente.

Comment: De fato, falha minha.

Answer (score 1):

Sabendo que cada caractere da frase tem 8 bits basta fazer isso:

```
String str = "Algum texto";
int numDeBits = str.length * 8;
```

Não sei se é bem essa a sintaxe do java mas qualquer coisa deixa um comentario que eu tento arrumar.

Comment: E se o texto estiver codificado em utf-8? Pode existir caracteres que ocupam mais de 8 bits.

Comment: no caso vai ocupar 9 dai ne?

Comment: caracteres acentuados podem aumentar o tamanho de bytes numa string, mesmo com o mesmo número de caracteres, por isso o melhor é contar o número de bytes da String.

Comment: ah entao a resposta de baixo esta correta.